# How below program doesn't work for checking set bit

Tags: c

I am just revising C concepts and was making a program for checking the set bit.
I wrote below snippet,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char a, checkbit;
    scanf(" %c", &a);
    scanf(" %c", &checkbit);
    printf("%u\n", (a & (1 << checkbit)));
    if (a & (1 << checkbit))
        printf("bit is 1\n");
    else
        printf("bit is 0\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Above program always give me "bit is 0"
Changing checkbit variable to int then it works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char a;
    int checkbit;
    scanf(" %c", &a);
    scanf(" %d", &checkbit);
    printf("%u\n", (a & (1 << checkbit)));
    if (a & (1 << checkbit))
        printf("bit is 1\n");
    else
        printf("bit is 0\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the 1st program?

Tried here also

[online_gcc_compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)

same result.

Comment: you realize you're reading `checkbit` as a character in the first snippet? So, for example entering `0` doesn't correspond to bit 0, it corresponds to bit 48.

Comment: Undefined behavior for shift of greater than or equal positions to the number of bits of the shifted type.

Comment: Be sure to use a debugger so you can see that scanf() doesn't do what you think it does.  http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: got it. silly question :(

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question, but the answer is probably unsatisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%hhu` to get an integer value instead of a character:

```
scanf(" %hhu", &checkbit);
```

Your code currently stores the ASCII (or whatever other character set you're using) representation of the number you're entering in `checkbit`.

Note that this won't work on Windows; MSVCRT isn't C99-compliant.

Comment: Both snippets are wrong,  I should have used unsigned int to keep things simple. First one works just out of luck. The intention was to use smallest sized variable, and out of habit I used unsigned character. Will remember to use %hhu on with gcc.

Comment: @nikhilchaubey I would argue for `unsigned short` if you want to keep things small.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this for the input:

```
scanf(" %c", &checkbit);
```

you have to input characters with the code 0x01 ... 0x16, which is quite difficult, because these are special codes and you won't be able to easily type most of them on your keyboard.

For example, f you try to input `1` -- this will come as ASCII code 49 -- and the number of bit you'll be checking is way above what you're expecting to.

This is why getting your input as an integer is the preferred way in situations like yours.